# Code to strip non-alpha characters from string in Python

Tags: python

I want to write a code that will take out all Non-Alpha character from a string. Alpha Characters are a-z,A-Z,and 0-9. So this code will also remove spaces but not crash on an empty string.
For example:

```
to_alphanum('Cats go meow')
#it would return:
'Catsgomeow'

to_alphanum('')
#it would return:
''
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: You may want to read the [regular expression library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html), try to create a solution from that, and update your question. `\W` is a good place to start.

Comment: Well, to start with - you can use a simple `if` statement to rule out empty strings so then it won't crash. And then it's probably a case of using regular expressions (regex) as @Nathan mentioned.

Comment: I've tried checking if there was a non-alpha in the code before executing but I'm not sure how to remove those characters and keep the rest of the string.

Comment: Did you successfully identify the non-alpha characters? Or were you having problems finding them as well as removing them?

Comment: I could find them but not remove them successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str` has `isalnum` method to check for alphanumerics, leverage that:

```
In [115]: def to_alphanum(text): 
     ...:     return ''.join([char for char in text if char.isalnum()]) 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [116]: to_alphanum('Cats go meow')                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[116]: 'Catsgomeow'

In [117]: to_alphanum('#$')                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[117]: ''

In [118]: to_alphanum('190 $%6')                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[118]: '1906'
```

Comment: I didn't even think of doing it that way, thank you so much!